# OpenGL 4.1 not using entire vertex attributes at locations above 0

Tags: c++, opengl

I was drawing a 2D image on screen, and it was working successfully until I decided to add a color attribute.  When I did this, I noticed the shader set the color of the entire image only to the first four components of my color buffer (which has 24 components).

Initialization:

```
//These are scaled before drawing
GLfloat vertex_buffer_data[] = {

    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f

};

glGenBuffers( 1, &m_2DVertexBuffer );
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_2DVertexBuffer );
glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof( vertex_buffer_data ), vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW );

//Simply test values to see which values the shader uses.  Only uses the first 4.
GLfloat color_buffer_data[] = {

    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
};

glGenBuffers( 1, &m_2DColorBuffer );
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_2DColorBuffer );
glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof( color_buffer_data ), color_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW );
```

Binding:

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray( 0 );
glEnableVertexAttribArray( 1 );

glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_2DVertexBuffer );
glVertexAttribPointer( 0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, ( void * )0 );


glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_2DColorBuffer );
glVertexAttribPointer( 1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, ( void * )0 );
```

Drawing:

```
glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 6 );
```

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 410

layout( location = 0 ) in vec3 position;
layout( location = 1 ) in vec4 color;

out vec2 textureCoord;
out vec4 textureColor;

uniform mat4 ProjView;
uniform mat4 ModelMat;
uniform mat4 ViewMat;

void main()
{

   vec4 pos = vec4( position.x, position.y, position.z, 1 );

   textureColor = color;
   textureCoord = pos.xy;

   gl_Position = ProjView * ModelMat * ViewMat * pos;

}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 410


in vec2 textureCoord;
in vec4 textureColor;

uniform sampler2D texUnit;

out vec4 outputColor;


void main()
{

   outputColor = texture( texUnit, textureCoord ) * textureColor;

}
```

I'm on OSX 10.9, if it matters.

Comment: Why do you want to add a colour buffer when you're texturing the vertices with a 2D image? You only need UV coordinates for that.

Comment: To tint the texture certain shades + add an alpha value for transparency.

Comment: I'm novice with vao, vbo, but are you not missing to generate a vao with `glGenVertexArray()` to combine your buffers for the `glDrawArrays`?

Comment: There is a VAO generated and already binded, I just omitted it from the code I posted.

Comment: Fair enough. Have you unbound the VAO after drawing?

Comment: Nope.  I bound it once in my code, and left it bound (arguably inefficient).